# Can we use yarn for adding capacitor plugin

Tags: hadoop-yarn, capacitor, npx, capacitor-plugin

I am working on a react project using yarn dependencies .Need to add capacitor plugin to a react project.But there is an issue on adding capacitor plugin and link
capacitor to project.To create a capacitor plugin ,i use the command "npx @capacitor/cli plugin:generate" .Can I add the plugin usng yarn. I refer the document - https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/creating-plugins

Comment: Is this work ??

Answer (score 2):

In `capacitor.config.json` just set `"npmClient" : "yarn"`

Here's a full example

```
{
  "appId": "com.example.test",
  "appName": "Example",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "webDir": "dist",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 3000
    }
  },
  "cordova": {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should work. You already created the plugin via `npx`. So to test, substitute the `npm` commands in the docs with yarn. For [local testing](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/workflow#local-testing):

In your plugin folder

```sh
$ yarn link
```

Then in the capacitor project to test your plugin:

```sh
$ yarn link plugin-name
$ yarn install plugin-name
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But after creating the capacitor plugin.Need to build it using 'npm run build'  should i use yarn command there alsoo.I used yarn .it returns error.please help met to do that capacitor creation  using yarn